# uniqueness of Morita equivalence bimodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Two separable algebras over a field are Morita equivalent iff they have an invertible bimodule. If it exists, is this bimodule unique (up to something)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because there exist separable algebras with many autoequivalences. The group of autoequivalences of an algebra is called the Picard group and it is very often non trivial.

Consider the product A of two copies of the ground field. There are two isomorphism classes  of invertible A-bimodules.

Comment: If A is a product of n copies of the field, then there are n! invertible bimodule.

Comment: Ah, this make sense. Can a matrix algebra (say, over a perfect field, if it makes a difference) have auto-equivalences?

Comment: A matrix algebra is Morita equivalent to the ground field, so its Picard group is trivial.

Comment: OK, right. An auto-equivalence on the matrix algebra would induce one on the ground field, which doesn't exist. I suppose if one cared about invertible modules themselves, rather than their isomorphism classes, one would get a PGL(n,k) due to conjugating some fixed invertible module by every matrix.